# Prove that :$a_{2k+1}=0$ and $a_{2k}<0$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms, power-series

Define the function for $0<x<1$ :

$$f(x)=\left(x^{-2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{-2x}\right)\left(\ln\left(x^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2x}\right)\right)$$

---

Claim :

The power series of $f(x)$ have for coefficients (for $x=0.5$) : $a_{2k+1}=0$ and $a_{2k}<0$ with $k\geq 1$ a natural number .

---

I can show that it's true for the first coefficents but I haven't a real strategy to prove the remainders . In fact I have tried to use the product rule (Leibniz) combined to an induction but I don't see all the steps to get the end . On th other hand the nice news is that the negatives coefficients increase as $k\to  \infty$ so it seems to be easier to show .The other good news is that a part of the derivatives is deleted because the function in the logarithm have value  one as $x=0.5$ and as everybody knows  $\ln(1)=0$.

Edit : It seems that there are some similarity between the function $f(x)$ and $g(x)=\ln((1-x)^2x^2)\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ on $[0.5,1)$.So the idea is to compare respectively the coefficients of the two functions.

---

Question :

How to show the claim ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: **IDEA** Define $g(x):=f(x-1/2)$ and try to show that this function is even

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=\ln\left(x^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2x}\right)\cdot \left(x^{-2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{-2x}\right)$?

Comment: @RiverLi. As I wrote, there is a misinterpretation somewhere

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, according to his first comment on your answer, he used that form in WA.

Comment: If you put brackets around the argument of the logarithm, it would be clearer. As I read it, it is $$f(x)=\ln\Bigg[\left(x^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2x}\right)\left(x^{-2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{-2x}\right)\Bigg]$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici sorry it was no clear.See my edit.

Comment: @RiverLi Yes it was a typo .

Comment: Why didn't you do react after seing my first equation where everything was inside the logarithm and before reacting ? OK, another problem with your favorite symmetry ! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici All my apologize...I'm a little busy this time.Don't take it for you .Je suis une tête en l'air !I have my head in the clouds!

Comment: Please, don't worry at all ! No problem (*si je puis dire !*). Cheers :-)

Comment: @ErikSatie Why not $f(x)=\left(x^{-2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{-2x}\right) \ln\left(x^{2(1-x)}+(1-x)^{2x}\right)$?

Comment: @ErikSatie What's the motivation of the question? Is there some connection between it and the inequality $a^{2b} + b^{2a} \le 1$ for all $a, b> 0$ with $a + b = 1$?

Comment: @RiverLi Yes you're right It's an attempt to find another way .

Answer (score 1):

**Before the edit of the question**

As @Tito Eliatron commented, let $x=y+\frac 12$ and consider the function
$$g(y)=\log \left(16^{-y} \left(1-4 y^2\right)^{-2 y-1} \left((1-2 y) \left(1-4
   y^2\right)^{2 y}+16^y (2 y+1)\right)^2\right)$$
Now, compute $g(y)-g(-y)$ and simplify
$$g(y)-g(-y)=0$$

For the second part, I suppose that I am mistaken since, for me, all the $a_{2k}$ are positive.

**Edit**

I do not know what is going on with the Wolfram Alpha results you sent me in comments. I wonder if there could be some misinterpretation somewhere.

I give you below the coefficients I obtained for the series (with $a=\log(2)$)

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & a_{2k} \\
 0 & 2 a \\
 1 & 4 a^2+8 a+4 \\
 2 & -\frac{8 a^4}{3}-\frac{32 a^3}{3}-16 a^2+16 a+24 \\
 3 & \frac{128 a^6}{45}+\frac{256 a^5}{15}+\frac{128 a^4}{3}+\frac{64 a^3}{3}-64
   a^2-32 a+\frac{208}{3} 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Concerning the numerical values of the coefficients, they vary so fast that I produce the logarithm of their decimal representation.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  k & \log(a_{2k}) \\
 0 & 0.32663 \\
 1 & 2.43947 \\
 2 & 3.14567 \\
 3 & 3.59466 \\
 4 & 4.91426 \\
 5 & 6.12503 \\
  6 & 7.24165 \\
 7 & 8.48159 \\
  8 & 9.74469
\end{array}
\right)$$

**After the edit of the question**

Doing the same as before, again, after simplification $$g(y)-g(-y)=0$$ Looking at the $a_{2k}$  (except $a_0=0$) and, still using $a=\log(2)$,
$$a_2=-16+16 a+8 a^2$$
$$a_4=-\frac{352}{3}+96 a+64 a^2+\frac{128 }{3}a^3+\frac{32 }{3}a^4$$ In fact, these coefficients also vary almost as exponential functions

Comment: Thanks claude (nice to see you again here!).See WA https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=taylor+series+%5Cln%5Cleft%28x%5E%7B2%281-x%29%7D%2B%281-x%29%5E%7B2x%7D%5Cright%29%5Cleft%28x%5E%7B-2%281-x%29%7D%2B%281-x%29%5E%7B-2x%7D%5Cright%29+at+x%3D0.5

Comment: @ErikSatie https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5BLog%5B%28%281+-+x%29%5E%28-2+x%29+%2B+x%5E%28-2+%281+-+x%29%29%29+%28%281+-+x%29%5E%282+x%29+%2B+x%5E%282+%281+-+x%29%29%29%5D%2C%7Bx%2C1%2F2%2C8%7D%5D

Comment: @ErikSatie https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot%5BLog%5B%28%281+-+x%29%5E%28-2+x%29+%2B+x%5E%28-2+%281+-+x%29%29%29+%28%281+-+x%29%5E%282+x%29+%2B+x%5E%282+%281+-+x%29%29%29%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D